# Download links from email

Tags: python-3.x, office365

I am trying to download pdf available in email as hyperlinks. The reason I need this is that I get emails with several such links that needs to be downloaded and saved on a location.
[image]

Is there a way this could be automated. Tried checking out ways to do it using python or VBA but no viable solutions so far. This is O365 that I need help on and the hyperlink is embedded in the text highlighted in blue..

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `smtp,smtpd` modules for a direct interaction with the server.

In the smtp **server** module you could download the mail locally and extract the info directly and locally, it's useful if you want to keep a backup of your mail, and keep clean your inbox.

In the `smtp` **client** module, you could read the email, save it as a object and extract the elements with the mime module, the extract (file) should be translated to a file object and/or saved in de pc as a file with it's extension.

> **Note:** you should look in the internet for the configuration of your mail service to connect in the correct way and the correct sequence of steps, because some servers need a validation of the connection before login and others after the login.